# Paste rows if criteria from dropdown lists match the data in the table: skip part of the code if a cell containing a dropdown list is left blank

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu, copy-paste

On the worksheet “Manager”, the user selects in dropdown lists the criteria that will be used to create a quotation. Once all the criteria are selected, he runs the below macro. The macro searches in the columns “Company”, “Info A”, and “Info B” of the worksheet “Data” the matching criteria. Every time it finds one row where the 3 criteria match, it copies the range P:W from the matching row and paste it to the worksheet “Quotation ENG” in A:H.

As long as the 3 criteria in “Manager” are filled, the corresponding ranges will be pasted in the “Quotation ENG”. But if one or two of the criteria are left blank in the “Manager”, then nothing is pasted in the “Quotation ENG”. It is normal because there are no blank cells in the “Data” table and the AND statement in the code links all criteria together.

It is not the behavior I want. I need to skip the search-copy-paste of any criterion which is left blank in “Manager”. For example in the below picture, the criterion from the cell E9, “Info B”, is left blank, and so it should only search the results for the criteria “Company/Brand” and “Info A” in the “Data” sheet.

[Sample view of the 3 worksheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T59wP.png)

```
Sub Quote()

    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet
    Dim Manager As Worksheet
    Dim Company() As String
    Dim InfoA As String
    Dim InfoB As String
    Dim Finalrow As Integer
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim I As Integer

    Set Source = Worksheets("Data")
    Set Target = Worksheets("Quotation ENG")
    Set Manager = Worksheets("Manager")
    Company = Split(Worksheets("Manager").Range("E5").Value, ",")
    InfoA = Worksheets("Manager").Range("E7").Value
    InfoB = Worksheets("Manager").Range("E9").Value

    Finalrow = Source.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For counter = 0 To UBound(Company)

        For I = 2 To Finalrow
            If Source.Cells(I, 1) = Trim(Company(counter)) And Source.Cells(I, 2) = InfoA And Source.Cells(I, 3) = InfoB Then
               Source.Range(Source.Cells(I, 16), Source.Cells(I, 23)).Copy Target.Range("A200").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 8)
            End If
        Next I
    Next counter

    Target.Activate
    Target.Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

== EDIT ==

Here is the working after the modifications from elektrykalAJ.

Sub Quote()

```
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet
Dim Manager As Worksheet
Dim Company() As String
Dim InfoA As String
Dim InfoB As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim counter As Integer
Dim I As Integer

Set Source = Worksheets("Data")
Set Target = Worksheets("Quotation ENG")
Set Manager = Worksheets("Manager")
InfoA = Worksheets("Manager").Range("E7").Value
InfoB = Worksheets("Manager").Range("E9").Value
finalrow = Source.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

If Worksheets("Manager").Range("E5").Value <> vbNullString Then
Company = Split(Worksheets("Manager").Range("E5").Value, ",")
Else
Company = Split("", "")
End If

For counter = 0 To UBound(Company)
lookupComp = Trim(Company(counter))

For I = 2 To finalrow

    thisComp = Source.Cells(I, 1)
    thisInfA = Source.Cells(I, 2)
    thisInfB = Source.Cells(I, 3)

    If (thisComp = lookupComp Or lookupComp = vbNullString) Then
        If (thisInfA = InfoA Or InfoA = vbNullString) Then
            If (thisInfB = InfoB Or InfoB = vbNullString) Then
                Source.Range(Source.Cells(I, 16), Source.Cells(I, 23)).Copy Target.Range("A200").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 8)
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next I
Next counter

Target.Activate
Target.Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: In your `Data` worksheet, is there only a single row where there is a blank entry for each of the "Company" and "InfoA" lookup values? For instance, if there are multiple lines that DO NOT have a "Company", then the logic of selecting _what_ to copy is going to change. More info needed...

Comment: If you can add a clearer pic showing which tab is which and where the data is coming from, etc., as well as a expected values for a few scenarios, that would be helpful.

Comment: It was too long for a comment, so I edited my original post. Let me know if it is still unclear. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Two things:**

1. If you don't want the code to "stop" when any of the criteria is blank, then you'll need to add some `Or` statements to your logic:

   > If the *"lookup value"* is blank **OR** the *"current value"* equals the *"lookup value"* then...
2. The efficient way to check for an empty string in VBA is to compare with `vbNullString`:

   `If value = vbNullString Then ...`

---

**Here is your modified code:**

I extracted some variables and replaced the `And` statements with `If` statements just to make it easier to read. I also made the variables lowercase:

```vba
For counter = 0 To UBound(company)
    lookupComp = Trim(company(counter))

    For I = 2 To finalrow
        
        thisComp = source.Cells(I, 1)
        thisInfA = source.Cells(I, 2)
        thisInfB = source.Cells(I, 3)
        
        If (thisComp = lookupComp Or lookupComp = vbNullString) Then
            If (thisInfA = infoA Or infoA = vbNullString) Then
                If (thisInfB = infoB Or infoB = vbNullString) Then
                    source.Range(source.Cells(I, 16), source.Cells(I, 23)).Copy target.Range("A200").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 8)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next I
Next counter
```

---

**Bonus:**

If *"Company"* could be blank, then add this check when you define the `company` variable:

```vba
If Worksheets("Manager").Range("E5").Value <> vbNullString Then
    company = Split(Worksheets("Manager").Range("E5").Value, ",")
Else
    company = Split("", "")
End If
```

---

Here is a clearer picture of what the OP is trying to do:

[image: Screenshot of tabs]

Comment: Late reply, sorry. I needed to find time to test and study your code. It works great, thanks a lot. I also thank you for the pedagogical explanation, it is appreciated.

Comment: Also, I'm almost done with that macro and I'm now stuck with one more issue. To make it easier to understand, I just asked for 3 parameters (Company, Info A, Info B). As you can see in the picture, I have 7 parameters and for 2 of them (Company and Product) I need to be able to select multiple criteria. I did not find how to make the counter work not only for the Company range but also for the Product range. I guess I should add a variable with an array to gather multiple counters and link these counters inside with And operator, but I could not find a way to do it.

Comment: Glad that worked out. For the Products, you should be able to loop though those inside of a loop just like you did for Company. Put that loop INSIDE of the Company loop just before you start looping through the rows.

Comment: So far all what I tried did not work. I posted a new question about it and if by chance you have some ideas about what I missed:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55516736/set-up-a-variable-with-multiple-if-statements-linked-to-a-for-loop-with-a-counte

Comment: I fixed it with a slightly different approach. It seems the word "counter" is somehow a reserved variable in Excel VBA. I changed it and named with letter J (for the Company). Then  I added one more FOR NEXT with a variable named K (for the Product) and now I can select multiple criteria for both.

Comment: Are you sure `counter` is reserved? I think the `Dim counter as Integer` part will override any built-in variables, but not sure. Were you trying to use the same variable for BOTH loops possibly? But glad to hear you found a solution.

Comment: It is just my assumption and I could not find any documentation to confirm or infirm it. I came to the conclusion it is a reserved variable because the ("bugged") results I got were same whatever if I used     Dim counter As Integer for both loops or if I used     Dim counterComp As Integer and     Dim counterProd As Integer. But exactly same code with letters     J and     K runs smoothly.