# Set up a variable with multiple IF statements linked to a FOR loop with a counter

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, counter

I have 3 sheets. In the sheet "Manager", there are 7 dropdown lists for criteria: `H5`, `H7`, `H9`, `H11`, `H13`, `H15`, `H17`. Once the criteria are selected and the user clicks on the button "COPY", the macro searches in the sheet "Data" columns `A:G` the rows matching the selected criteria. Then it copies the range `P:W` for the matching rows and pastes it in sheet "Quote" starting from row 11. It is important to note when the user does not select a criterion for any of the dropdown list, then that criterion is just ignored (see `VbNullString` in the code)

By now, the macro runs fine with multiple criteria selection for the Company dropdown list (`H5`) and single criterion selection for the others (`H7`, `H9`, `H11`, `H13`, `H15`, `H17`).

[image]

```
Sub Quote()

Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet
Dim Manager As Worksheet
Dim Multiple () As String 'Here
Dim InfoA As String
Dim InfoB As String
Dim InfoC As String
Dim ProductType As String
Dim SalesStatus As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim counter As Integer
Dim I As Integer

Set Source = Worksheets("Data")
Set Target = Worksheets("Quote")
Set Manager = Worksheets("Manager")
If Worksheets("Manager").Range("H5").Value <> vbNullString Then 'Here
Multiple = Split(Worksheets("Manager").Range("H5").Value, ",") 'Here
   If Worksheets("Manager").Range("H13").Value <> vbNullString Then 'Modified
   Multiple = Split(Worksheets("Manager").Range("H13").Value, ",") 'Here

      Else 'Here
      Multiple = Split("", "") 'Here
   End If 'Here
End If 'Here
InfoA = Worksheets("Manager").Range("H7").Value
InfoB = Worksheets("Manager").Range("H9").Value
InfoC = Worksheets("Manager").Range("H11").Value
ProductType = Worksheets("Manager").Range("H15").Value
SalesStatus = Worksheets("Manager").Range("H17").Value
finalrow = Source.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


For counter = 0 To UBound(Multiple) 'Here
lookupMult = Trim(Multiple(counter)) 'Here

For I = 2 To finalrow

    thisComp = Source.Cells(I, 1)
    thisInfA = Source.Cells(I, 2)
    thisInfB = Source.Cells(I, 3)
    thisInfC = Source.Cells(I, 4)
    thisProd = Source.Cells(I, 5)
    thisType = Source.Cells(I, 6)
    thisSale = Source.Cells(I, 7)

    If (thisComp = lookupMult Or lookupMult = vbNullString) Then 'Here
        If (thisInfA = InfoA Or InfoA = vbNullString) Then
            If (thisInfB = InfoB Or InfoB = vbNullString) Then
                If (thisInfC = InfoC Or InfoC = vbNullString) Then
                    If (thisProd = lookupMult Or lookupMult = vbNullString) Then 'Here
                        If (thisType = ProductType Or ProductType = vbNullString) Then
                            If (thisSale = SalesStatus Or SalesStatus = vbNullString) Then
                    Source.Range(Source.Cells(I, 16), Source.Cells(I, 23)).Copy Target.Range("A200").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 8)
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next I
Next counter

End Sub
```

In addition to the multiple criteria selection for `H5`, I need also to enable it for the Product (`H13`). To do so, I tried to modify the variable Company using a more elaborated IF statement. In the picture, the sheet "Quote" is the result I should get. But in fact nothing is copy-pasted and I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. I added some comments 'Here to show what part of the code I modified. By advance thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Instead of having so many `IF's`, try filtering the columns based on your criteria and then copy the displayed rows (if any)

Comment: You could SQL query your data in sheet data, and return with a Select Query the rows that match your criteria. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755396/performing-sql-queries-on-an-excel-table-within-a-workbook-with-vba-macro

Comment: I did not know it was possible to do SQL query in Excel. Thanks a lot for the link, I started to check it and I'm also learning with some tutorials I found on the Web. In the meantime, if someone knows a way to do it with the code I'm already using, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve my issue. It is not a silver bullet, but at least it works as it should. After, if anyone knows some way to optimize the code, outside of SQL queries and structured tables, feel free to share and I will try. Note I believe SQL queries is probably a better option, but it means I have to rework almost all my code and use methods I do not know (yet). I will study it later for a future update.

The problem is the word "counter" might be a reserved variable. So, I was not authorized to add another FOR in my loop sharing similar features. Since I changed the "counter" variable by letters, I'm now able to do multiple criteria selection for other dropdown lists. In the example below, I just made it for H5 and H13 in order to keep it clear.

```
Sub Quote()

Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet
Dim Manager As Worksheet
Dim Company () As String
Dim InfoA As String
Dim InfoB As String
Dim InfoC As String
Dim Product () As String
Dim ProductType As String
Dim SalesStatus As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim I As Integer
Dim J As Integer
Dim K As Integer

Set Source = Worksheets("Data")
Set Target = Worksheets("Quote")
Set Manager = Worksheets("Manager")
If Worksheets("Manager").Range("H5").Value <> vbNullString Then 
Company= Split(Worksheets("Manager").Range("H5").Value, ",") 
Else 
Company = Split("", "") 
End If 
InfoA = Worksheets("Manager").Range("H7").Value
InfoB = Worksheets("Manager").Range("H9").Value
InfoC = Worksheets("Manager").Range("H11").Value
If Worksheets("Manager").Range("H13").Value <> vbNullString Then 
Product = Split(Worksheets("Manager").Range("H13").Value, ",") 
Else 
Product = Split("", "") 
End If 
ProductType = Worksheets("Manager").Range("H15").Value
SalesStatus = Worksheets("Manager").Range("H17").Value
finalrow = Source.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


For K = 0 To UBound(Company) 
lookupComp = Trim(Company(K))

For J = 0 To UBound(Product) 
lookupProd = Trim(Product(J))  

For I = 2 To finalrow

thisComp = Source.Cells(I, 1)
thisInfA = Source.Cells(I, 2)
thisInfB = Source.Cells(I, 3)
thisInfC = Source.Cells(I, 4)
thisProd = Source.Cells(I, 5)
thisType = Source.Cells(I, 6)
thisSale = Source.Cells(I, 7)

If (thisComp = lookupComp Or lookupComp = vbNullString) Then
    If (thisInfA = InfoA Or InfoA = vbNullString) Then
        If (thisInfB = InfoB Or InfoB = vbNullString) Then
            If (thisInfC = InfoC Or InfoC = vbNullString) Then
                If (thisProd = lookupProd Or lookupProd = vbNullString) Then
                    If (thisType = ProductType Or ProductType = vbNullString) Then
                        If (thisSale = SalesStatus Or SalesStatus = vbNullString) Then
                Source.Range(Source.Cells(I, 16), Source.Cells(I, 23)).Copy Target.Range("A200").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 8)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
Next I
Next J
Next K

End Sub
```